# exit git log without pressing q after showing the log

Tags: git, terminal

So I have an alias for git log which prints out the format which i like. I only display 8 commits so I know that will always fit the screen without the need of scrolling capability.

How can I embed the :q less command into my alias?

this is the full alias:

> git log --pretty=format:"[%C(auto)%h][%Cgreen%an%Creset]%C(auto)%d %s (%Cblue%ar%Creset)" --graph --color -8

Comment: What are your values of `$LESS`, `$GIT_PAGER` and `$PAGER` in your `bash` environment, and the output of `git config --get-all core.pager`? If none of those are set, and `git` wasn't configured differently at compile time, the default should be essentially `less -FRSX`, which should exit automatically if there's less than a page of output.